# Explode multiple user Ids

Tags: php, mysql

Im having trouble getting explode to work I have a table field named Attending with multiple user Ids separated with commas 73,1,5 right now i can easily get user 73 to echo out but need explode for the rest, I want it to echo out each username of those 3 users or however many it ends up being. I was thinking it might be something like what i commented out with the //

Attending Field is list of users
http://imageshack.us/a/img38/1425/eventsne.jpg

Trying to Echo out like this once i get username working ill do the avatar and in a table
http://imageshack.us/a/img819/8210/events2d.jpg

```
$Attending1 = array(); 
$Attending1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events, Users WHERE Events.Attending = Users.UserId");

//$AttendingUserIds = $Attending1['Attending'];
//$AttendingExploded = explode(",", $AttendingUserIds);

//$Attending3 = array();
//$Attending3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events, Users WHERE $AttendingExploded = Users.UserId");


while ($Attending2 = mysql_fetch_array($Attending1)) {
    echo $Attending2['username'];
}
```

---

Just tryed KyleK 3rd suggestion

```
$Attending1 = array();
$Attending1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events, Users WHERE Events.Attending = Users.UserId");

$AttendingUserIds = $Attending1['Attending'];
//$AttendingExploded = explode(",", $AttendingUserIds);

$Attending3 = array();
$Attending3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events, Users WHERE Users.UserId IN ($AttendingUserIds)");
```

It gives me Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource where the While starts.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood you in my first answer.....you have a row, and the ID's come from the database in a comma seperated list....then you want to query the database for each of that list of comma seperated values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in just one `SELECT`, by joining `Events` and `Users` tables thru the `find_in_set()` function. That way, you will get all users which attended each event, because `find_in_set()` will look up the first parameter in the CSV string supplied as the second parameter. You may also want to add a `WHERE` to filter a specific event. And don't forget to replace the * with only the fields you need, to avoid unnecessary data traffic:

```
$Attending = array(); 
$Attending = mysql_query("
  SELECT * 
  FROM Events e
  INNER JOIN Users u ON find_in_set(u.UserId, e.Attending) 
");
```

Comment: yay it worked i tryed to give you a vote up but it said i need 15 reputation.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$Attending1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events, Users WHERE Events.Attending = Users.UserId");
   while ($Attending2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Attending1)) {
    $arr[] = $Attending2['username'];
}
```

`mysql_query` doesn't give you an array, `fetch_array` (or `fetch_assoc`) does.

Its result will be similar to this: `$arr[0]['username'], $arr[1]['username'], $arr[2]['username']`, etc. I don't know how you want to "explode" so I can't answer, but after `fetch_assoc` you should get an array.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you have values in a string that are comma seperated "73, 3, 5".
So then just use WHERE IN

Your string of values from the database, however you gonna get it...

```
$stringofids = "73,3,3";//You will obviously retrieve these from database
```

Then just pass that string into another query, with a WHERE IN statement...
That will return an array of all the users attending.

```
$AttendingUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events, Users WHERE Users.UserId IN ($stringofids)");

while ($Attending = mysql_fetch_array($AttendingUsers)) {
echo $Attending['username'];
}
```

Comment: Attending Field is list of users http://imageshack.us/a/img38/1425/eventsne.jpg

Trying to Echo out like this once i get username working ill do the avatar and in a table http://imageshack.us/a/img819/8210/events2d.jpg

Comment: Ok., then my solution above should work, doing a WHERE IN query